# When I trying to change a string while file open but it does unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, string, file

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        FILE *wf = fopen("test.txt", "w");
        fwrite("Hey, sub!\nAre you good?\nOh, hi!", 1, 34, wf);
        fclose(wf);
    
        char *buffer = (char*) malloc(34);
        char *buffer_temp = (char*) malloc(35);
        FILE *rf = fopen("test.txt", "w+");
        fread(buffer, 34, 1, rf);
    
        int i = 0;
        while(34 > i)
        {
            buffer_temp[i] = buffer[i];
            i+=1;
        }
        buffer[i] = '\0';
    
        fwrite(buffer_temp, 1, 35, rf);
        fclose(rf);
    
        free(buffer);
        free(buffer_temp);
        return 0;
    }
```

I trying this code but in between `FILE *rf` section and `fclose(rf)` section it does unexpected behaviour. I tried in ansi-c and other standards but results was same. Do you know this error reason? I'm currently trying to code parser-like system but this unexpected behaviour appeared.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "it does unexpected behaviour." You might need to be a bit more precise. What did it do? What did you expect?

Comment: I'd expect a `rewind()` before `fwrite(buffer_temp, 1, 35, rf);` to change the string.

Comment: `fwrite("Hey, sub!\nAre you good?\nOh, hi!", 1, 34, wf);` is a problem if  size of `"Hey, sub!\nAre you good?\nOh, hi!"` is less than 34, which it is.

Comment: Your string is less than 34 bytes. You seem to count `\n` as 2 characters.

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot using ``` rewind() ``` function sorry for that. So I did it wrong because it could exceed memory.  How can I solve that problem?

Comment: `buffer[i] = '\0'` is undefined when `i == 34`, which is the case at the end of the loop.  You probably meant to assign to `buffer_temp[i]`.